# How to count the number of sundays between two dates

Tags: javascript

I tried the JS below:

```js
var start = new Date("25-05-2016");
var finish = new Date("31-05-2016");
var dayMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
var weekendDays = 0;
while (start <= finish) {
  var day = start.getDay()
  if (day == 0) {
    weekendDays++;
  }
  start = new Date(+start + dayMilliseconds);
}
alert(weekendDays);
```

However, it gives the wrong output.

I need to get the **total count of Sundays** between the two dates.

Comment: Where here in PHP question? The question does not apply to PHP

Comment: Given code is no where close to what you need....;)

Comment: You don't need a loop to do this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use incorrect **date format**.It will work if init date so:

```
var start = new Date("2016-05-25");
var finish = new Date("2016-05-31");
```

Comment: Surely. Or is this question how to convert?

Comment: Not sure above solution worked based on question

Answer (score 5):

Your date format is wrong. Dates' string format is `"yyyy-mm-dd"`. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) for more information.

Also, looping each day of the interval is very inefficient. You may try the following instead.

```js
function getNumberOfWeekDays(start, end, dayNum){
  // Sunday's num is 0 with Date.prototype.getDay.
  dayNum = dayNum || 0;
  // Calculate the number of days between start and end.
  var daysInInterval = Math.ceil((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / (1000 * 3600 * 24));
  // Calculate the nb of days before the next target day (e.g. next Sunday after start).
  var toNextTargetDay = (7 + dayNum - start.getDay()) % 7;
  // Calculate the number of days from the first target day to the end.
  var daysFromFirstTargetDay = Math.max(daysInInterval - toNextTargetDay, 0);
  // Calculate the number of weeks (even partial) from the first target day to the end.
  return Math.ceil(daysFromFirstTargetDay / 7);
}


var start = new Date("2016-05-25");
var finish = new Date("2016-05-31");

console.log("Start:", start);
console.log("Start's week day num:", start.getDay());
console.log("Finish:", finish);
console.log("Finish's week day num:", finish.getDay());

console.log("Number of Sundays:", getNumberOfWeekDays(start, finish));
```

Comment: This gives you `3` instead of `4` , for dates `2020-07-01` and `2020-07-26`, it does not include the Sunday of the `endDate` `2020-07-26` This answer fixes the issue [stack overflow answer 26629860](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629860/find-the-number-of-sunday-between-two-dates-and-if-sunday-comes-between-two-date)

Comment: @MAYOBYOHASSAN, I simply added `1` to `daysInInterval` variable, thus it will look like `const daysInInterval = Math.ceil((end.getTime() - start.getTime()) / 864e5) + 1`. This way, it will always include the end date. One could update the function to add a parameter (e.g. `countEndDate: boolean`) and add that `1` based on its value.

Answer (score 2):

Your date format and comparison condition should change like the following:

```
var start = new Date("2016-05-11");
  var finish = new Date("2016-05-31");
  var dayMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var weekendDays = 0;
  while (start.getTime() <= finish.getTime()) {
    var day = start.getDay();
    if (day == 0) {
        weekendDays++;
    }
    start = new Date(+start + dayMilliseconds);
  }
  alert(weekendDays);
```

Check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjaykumarns/qq0zdsgt/)

Answer (score 2):

You are using incorrect date format.
Just Change the format to:

```
var start = new Date(2016, 4, 25);
var finish = new Date(2016, 4, 31);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function:

```
  function CalculateWeekendDays(fromDate, toDate){
        var weekendDayCount = 0;
        while(fromDate < toDate){
            fromDate.setDate(fromDate.getDate() + 1);
            if(fromDate.getDay() === 0){
                ++weekendDayCount ;
            }
        }
        return weekendDayCount ;
    }


console.log(CalculateWeekendDays(new Date(2011, 6, 2), new Date(2011, 7, 2)));
```

This will give you number of sunday come between 2 dates

Answer (score 0):

change your date format.It will work

```
var start = new Date("05-16-2016");
  var finish = new Date("05-31-2016");
  var dayMilliseconds = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  var weekendDays = 0;
  while (start <= finish) {
    var day = start.getDay()
    if (day == 0) {
        weekendDays++;
    }
    start = new Date(+start + dayMilliseconds);
  }
  console.log(weekendDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

JS date format doesn't have "dd-MM-yyyy" ,so it will invalid date format .Try recreate date is ok or just change your date format [Date Format](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp)

Try this:

```
var start = new Date("25-05-2016");
var end = new Date("31-05-2016");

var startDate = new Date(start);
var endDate = new Date(end);
var totalSundays = 0;

for (var i = startDate; i <= endDate; ){
    if (i.getDay() == 0){
        totalSundays++;
    }
    i.setTime(i.getTime() + 1000*60*60*24);
}

console.log(totalSundays);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Find date of sundays b/w two dates
var fromDate = new Date('2022-10-26')
var toDate = new Date('2022-11-31')
var sunday = 0
var milisec = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
while (fromDate <= toDate) {
    var day = fromDate.getDay()
    if (day == 0) {
        sunday++
        console.log('Date of sunday:', fromDate)
    }
    fromDate = new Date(+fromDate + milisec)
}
console.log('Total no. of sundays:', sunday)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).